# Using variable name with .data[[ ]], dplyr and for loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn some tidy evaluation from: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html.
I know the below can easily be done with:

```
apply(mtcars, 2, mean)
```

But for the sake of the exercise, how would I use the actual variable name in the summarise output below (i.e. replace "name" with the variable name):

```
data("mtcars")
for (var in names(mtcars)) {
  mtcars |> 
    summarise(name = mean(.data[[var]])) |> 
    print()
}
```

Comment: `summarise({{ var }} := mean(.data[[var]]))` note the `:=`.